# Get the count of events that the user has attended in Facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get the event count that I have attended in the last 6 months.
I am using graph api /user_id/events
but am not getting any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around with debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.

Ensure you granted **user_events** permission scope:

[image]

**FQL query:**

> SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() AND
>   rsvp_status='attending'

Example:

[image]

As you can see, only one event id  is attending.

For your case, it's more complicated because you have to compare the start_time in the range of last 6 months, and do pagination by start_time(get from last item of this page) accordingly. You can set a low LIMIT number to test. Put **ORDER BY start_time DESC** to make sure its pagination is based on **start_time**, not uid or something else.

[image]

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/